# Using closest() to navigate up a table DOM

Tags: jquery, mysql

I'm currently using *closest()* which navigates up the dom and using this to find the row element *tr* but it seems to be returning an empty alert dialog indicating that nothing is being retrieved. What am I doing wrong?

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.manage').click(function(){
  // find the row we are in
  var $self = $( self );
  var $row = $self.closest( 'tr' );

  // read the id
  var $idCell = $row.find( '.id' );
  var caseId = $idCell.text();

  alert(caseId);

  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
 <table border="0" class="sortable">
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Functions</th>
      </tr>
      <?php do { ?>
        <tr>
          <td class="id"><?php echo $row_cases['id'].'-'.$_GET["progress"]; ?></td>
          <td><img src="components/manage.png" width="16" height="16" class="manage">
        </tr>
        <?php } while ($row_cases = mysql_fetch_assoc($cases)); ?>
    </table>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `self` instead of `this`, there is no `self` in JavaScript. This should work:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('.manage').click(function(){
          // find the row we are in
          var $row = $( this ).closest( 'tr' );

          // read the id
          var $idCell = $row.find( '.id' );
          var caseId = $idCell.text();

          alert(caseId);
     });
});
```

Comment: FYI, there's not really ANY reason to use $self in this function at all.  Since it's only referenced once, they should just use `$(this).closest('tr')` and not create the intermediate variable.

Comment: Answer updated considering what @jfriend00 said. He is totally right!

Answer (score 1):

You want `this`, not `self`:

```
var $self = $(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Mostlikely, `var $self = $( self );` is supposed to be var `$self = $( this );`

Answer (score 0):

What is 'self' in the following line?

```
var $self = $( self );
```

Should it be like this?

```
v$('.manage').click(function(event) {
    // find the row we are in
    var $self = $( event.target );
```